# React-redux does not re-render on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just started with redux and react-redux. I am observing a very weird behavior and not able to wrap my head around it.

I am trying something like this.

```
const fetchedFolders = useSelector(state=>{
        console.log("redux state = ",state);
        return state.fetchedFolders;
    });

const updateFetchedFolders = useDispatch();
```

I have callback function that receives a new set of values and will update the state in store.

```
let appendFoldersToList=(newFolders)=>{
        console.log(typeof(newFolders))
        if(typeof(newFolders) === undefined)
            console.log("go to error");
        
        else{
            updateFetchedFolders(setFetchedFolders([...fetchedFolders,...newFolders]));
        }
    }
```

this works perfectly and re-renders the list with new value
but if I replace the line

```
updateFetchedFolders(setFetchedFolders([...fetchedFolders,...newFolders]));
```

with

```
updateFetchedFolders(setFetchedFolders([...newFolders]));
```

it does not re-render and it still shows the old list. but in console, I can see data is updated.

I am not able to understand why it re-renders in first case and not in second case.

This is how my reducers look:-

```
export const reducer = (state=initialState, action)=>{

    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_FOLDERS': return {
            ...state,
            fetchedFolders:[...action.payload]
        }
    }
}
```

this is my action creator:-

```
export const setFetchedFolders = (payload)=>{
    return {
        type:'SET_FOLDERS',
        payload:payload
    }
}
```

this is my initial state:-

```
const initialState = {
    fetchedFolders:[],
    
}
```

I don't think I am not mutating the state.

my array looks something like this::-

```
[
   {name:cats, id:SOME_ID},
   {name:dogs, id:SOME_ID}
]
```

Comment: Probably you are mutating the data set before it gets dispatched or in the process of dispatching it. Is your data set deeper than a shallow copy? If so you using a spread operator is not sufficient. Maybe share your example on a codesandbox so it can be debugged.

Comment: What is `setFetchedFolders`? Is it a `useState` setter?

Comment: setFetchedFolders is action creator.
export const setFetchedFolders = (payload)=>{
    return {
        type:'SET_FOLDERS',
        payload:payload
    }
}

Comment: this kind of thing happened to me once..., but i hard refreshed the browser and it started to work, can you try that too?

Comment: I think your dispatcher is returning a memoized callback that prevent the component from unnecessary renders. I would suggest that you pass "newFolders" as payload without spreading it and do the logic in the reducer. After you do this hard reload your app and see if it works as expected

Comment: I can see fetchedFolder is updated when I console.log it in useEffect but there is no re-render only the case 1 it re-renders